# JSDoc configuration to exclude output files

Tags: node.js, documentation, jsdoc

I'm writing up some API documentation for a Node/Express app with JSDoc. I have a simple configuration file set up when running `jsdoc ./routes -c config.json`:

```
{
  "source": {
    "includePattern": ".+\\.js(doc)?$",
    "excludePattern": "(^|\\/|\\\\)_"
  },
  "tags": {
    "allowUnknownTags": true,
    "dictionaries": ["jsdoc", "closure"]
  },
  "plugins": ["plugins/markdown"],
  "templates": {
    "cleverLinks": true,
    "monospaceLinks": true
  },
  "opts": {
    "destination": "docs",
    "recurse": true,
    "readme": "README.md"
  }
}
```

The command outputs a folder `/docs` with `fonts`, `scripts`, `styles`, and `index.html`. Is there a way to configure JSDoc to exclude outputting all directories besides a simple HTML file?I was thinking something like:

```
"output": {
    "exclude": ["fonts", "scripts", "styles"]
}
```